# Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$ are not partition generated

Tags: measure-theory

I want to prove that the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ can not  be generated by partition: There is not any family $\mathcal{C} = \{A_i : (A_i)_{i \in I}$ partition of $\mathbb{R} \}$ such that $\sigma (\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ .
Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- If $\mathcal C=\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$ is a partition then $A\in\sigma(\mathcal C)$ iff it can be written as $\bigcup_{i\in J}A_i$ where $J\subseteq I$ is countable or co-countable.
- singletons are Borel-measurable.
- There are Borel sets that are not countable and not cocountable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion: Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a class of subsets of a set $X$. Say  that two elements $x,y\in X$ are *separated by $\mathcal{C}$* if there is $C\in\mathcal{C}$ containing *only one* of $x,y$.

- Show that elements of $X$ are separated by $\mathcal{C}$ iff they are separated by $\sigma(\mathcal{C})$.
- Show that if $\mathcal{C}$ is a partition generating the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}$, then $\mathcal{C}$ consists of singleton sets.
- Show that $\sigma(C)$ consists of countable or co-countable sets, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

In my thought, if such a family $\mathcal C$ existed, it must contain singletons(since they are closed). Thus $\mathcal C$ must consist of every singletons in $\mathbb R$, while any open interval cannot be written as a *countable* union of singletons.

I'm not sure whether this is right, though.